# setting const strings equal in method c++?

Tags: c++, error-handling, equals-operator

I'm having trouble with the `removeItem` method because an error occurs right after it's called.
In this method I'm trying to set the array member with the `sku` in the argument to `nullptr` and "remove" it.
I think it has something to do with the equalization: `if(sku == shoppingList[i]->getSKU())`. Or maybe something to do with `const`. The array has pointers to objects of type `Product`.

This belongs to CustomerOrder.cpp

```
CustomerOrder::CustomerOrder()
: shoppingList()
{

}
void CustomerOrder::removeItem(const string &sku)
{
    for(int i =0; i< 20; i++)
    {
        if(sku == shoppingList[i]->getSKU())
        {
            shoppingList[i] = nullptr;
        }
    }
}
```

This belongs in Product.h

```
private:
std::string sku;
```

this belongs to Product.cpp

```
const string & Product::getSKU() const
{
    return sku;
}
```

Comment: What is the type of shoppingList? and why not use the erase/remove idiom?

Comment: private:
std::array<Product*, number> shoppingList;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the method the following way

```
void CustomerOrder::removeItem( const string &sku )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < shoppingList.size(); i++ )
    {
        if( shoppingList[i] && sku == shoppingList[i]->getSKU() )
        {
            delete shoppingList[i];
            shoppingList[i] = nullptr;
        }
    }
}
```

I think that the problem is that you tried to call a method for a pointer to Product that was already set to nullptr

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that your code isn't written to handle nullptr entries in your array.  Since you don't actually show where the error occurs or the type of shopping list, it's hard to say exactly what's going wrong.  Setting a `std::string*` to nullptr won't remove it from an array of type `std::string*`.  If you are interested in easy removal of items, consider a different data structure.